# (Good or bad?) Calling a Function in Template File which returns a theme() Function value

Tags: 7, theming

I have a function which get some values from a Term, calculates something and at the end of my function, there is a statement like this:

```
return theme('foo', array('bar' => 1);
```

This function is in a self-written module. In the same module, I've got a template file.

Now my question: is it good or bad Practice to call the function which one I describe above in the template file? I know that I could calculate all this before calling the template file, but with my solution, the could would be more readable.

Thank you in avantage for inputs.

Comment: It's bad practice. Template files are for display only, template preprocess functions are for building that display :) This has been asked and answered several times before on the site but I can't find a link right now...

Comment: When I use the template preprocess function, is it a good idea to split my (huge) template file in more and include them with the PHP require() function?

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about calling `theme()` from inside a template file, that is possible, but it is rarely done: Out of 214 calls to `theme()` done from Drupal (and the Views module) only two calls are done from inside s template file.

This is the code used in the default implementation of [page.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!page.tpl.php/7); similar code is present in the implementation of [page.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/themes!bartik!templates!page.tpl.php/7) for the Bartik theme.

```
<?php if ($main_menu || $secondary_menu): ?>
  <div id="navigation"><div class="section">
    <?php print theme('links__system_main_menu', array('links' => $main_menu, 'attributes' => array('id' => 'main-menu', 'class' => array('links', 'inline', 'clearfix')), 'heading' => t('Main menu'))); ?>
    <?php print theme('links__system_secondary_menu', array('links' => $secondary_menu, 'attributes' => array('id' => 'secondary-menu', 'class' => array('links', 'inline', 'clearfix')), 'heading' => t('Secondary menu'))); ?>
  </div></div> <!-- /.section, /#navigation -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

What you should do is initializing a variable in the preprocess function for the template file, and use that variable in the template file.

Truly, you should not put logic code in your template file; this means that, for example, code similar to the following one should not be used in a template file.

```
<?php if ($condition1): ?>
  <?php print theme('theme_1', $values1); ?>
<?php elseif ($condition2): ?>
  <?php print theme('theme_2', $values2); ?>
<?php elseif ($condition3): ?>
  <?php print theme('theme_3', $values3); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

If the code is similar to the following one, then it would be more acceptable, but I would still think of possible future versions of the code, and prefer using a variable in the preprocess function.

```
  <?php print theme('theme_1', $values1); ?>
  <?php print theme('theme_2', $values2); ?>
  <?php print theme('theme_3', $values3); ?>
```